# Node.js HTTPS request with username

Tags: http, node.js, https, request, httpclient

I'm trying to query api.whatever.com, but I also want to pass a USERNAME, such as in curl it would look like this:

https://USERNAME@api.whatever.com/

How do I write the client request in such a way that USERNAME gets sent properly to the API server.

Comment: Use a HTTP Header for authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to base64 encode the username.

```
url = "https://USERNAME@api.whatever.com/".replace("https://","").split("@");
// Buffer is global, no need for require.
url64 = "https://" + (new Buffer(url[0]).toString('base64')) + url[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

There's an explaination of the format you have to use as well as an example.